# Enquiry about if statements

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean-expression

```
public String toString() {

String details = number + ", " + RACE_DESCRIPTIONS[typeIndex] + "[" + date + "]" + ":";
if (!hasFinished) {
  details += "Race not finished";
} else if  (hasFinished = true) {
  details += "\n     1st: " + competitors[0].getName();
  details += "\n     2nd: " + competitors[1].getName();
  details += "\n     3rd: " + competitors[2].getName();
} else if {
  details += "n/a"; 
}
return details;
```

If the position has not been set then the string literal "n/a" should be returned instead of the person’s name. 
-I am trying to write an IF statement if 1st,2nd and 3rd is NOT true and that n/a is returned instead.

Comment: Don't use `=`. That's the assignment operator. Also `else if` expects a condition.

Comment: The code makes it look like hasFinished can have three states: true, false and something else?! Isn't hasFinished a boolean?

Comment: You specifically state that you want 3 clauses. What are you actually trying to test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will never get `details += "n/a"` executed for two reasons:

1. You're assigning `hasFinished` to `true` in the `if` (as other people point):

   ```
   else if  (hasFinished = true)
   ```

   It should be

   ```
   else if  (hasFinished)
   ```
2. Most important than this, your code has this form:

   ```
   if (false) {
       ...
   } else {
       if (true) {
       } else {
           //this is false, it was supposed to be hitted before
       }
   }
   ```

So even if you do the first fix, the logic behind doesn't have any sense. You should use another evaluation in the second `if` to handle the last `else` statement. For example:

```
if (!hasFinished) {
    ...
} else {
    //the hasFinished usage here has no sense, being commented
    //just left it to show this is supported
    //if (hasFinished && someValue <= someOtherValue) {
    if (someValue <= someOtherValue) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I assign "&&" greater than or less than boolean expressions?

Comment: @user2839383 yes you can.

Comment: different names are assigned to different array values. Do i have to specifically mention what names are above three and below three to initiate the third statement? They are all assigned to different values called position variable.

Comment: @user2839383 I do not understand your last question.

Comment: I'm sorry about that. I have edited my last question.

Comment: @user2839383 again, I do not understand your question. Looks like you want to print the next 3 names (4th, 5th and 6th positions) instead of the first three. You can do it if you want, but the question and the answer are focused about the `if` usage to reach your last block of code, and I hope my answer helps you to solve that riddle.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the information. Also I would like to know about one more thing. what should i do to make n/a appear in the case when the competitor has not finished the race? e.g.: 1st: David 2nd: n/a 3rd: n/a

Comment: @user2839383 how do you know if a competitor has finished the race, is there any field in your `Competitor` class (or whichever name it has) to know this?

Comment: position is assigned to arrays of competitors. For example, 1 is 1st place, 2 is 2nd place,3 is 3rd place and from 4th and so on, 0 is given as position.

Comment: @user2839383 the array index just indicates in which position is the competitor in the race, it is not an indicator if the competitor has crossed the goal line.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the `=` operator to compare `boolean` values -- that's the assignment operator, so it's always `true`.  It's already `boolean`, just use:

```
} else if (hasFinished) {
```

Additionally, either it's `false` or it's `true`, so there's no need for a third case.  You can remove

```
else if {
  details += "n/a"; 
}
```

which was syntactically incorrect anyway.

Comment: OP doesn't want to remove that part, note that the question is about how to reach that block of code.

Answer (score 0):

`=` is used for assignment and `==` is used for comparison. Use `==` instead of `=` in the following statement:

```
else if  (hasFinished = true)
```

this will actually assign hasFinished value true and also the condition will be evaluated to true always. Change it to:

```
else if  (hasFinished == true)
```

for doing the comparision instead of assignment

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to check if you actually have three finishers, and this makes up your else-if clause.

```
public String toString()
{
    String details = number + ", " + RACE_DESCRIPTIONS[typeIndex] + "[" + date + "]" + ":";
    if(!hasFinished) // The race has not yet finished.
    {
        details += "Race not finished";
    }
    else if(competitors.length >= 3) // Implies that hasFinished evaluated to true
    {
        details += "\n     1st: " + competitors[0].getName();
        details += "\n     2nd: " + competitors[1].getName();
        details += "\n     3rd: " + competitors[2].getName();
    }
    else // The race has finished, but there are less than three competitors
    {
        details += "n/a";
    }
    return details;
}
```

If you want to allow for less than three competitors, but still display 1st/2nd/3rd, you can use a ternary comparison and replace your else-if clause with an else.

```
public String toString()
{
    String details = number + ", " + RACE_DESCRIPTIONS[typeIndex] + "[" + date + "]" + ":";
    if(!hasFinished)
    {
        details += "Race not finished";
    }
    else // Implies that hasFinished evaluated to true
    {
        details += "\n     1st: " + (competitors.length >= 1 ? competitors[0].getName() : "n/a");
        details += "\n     2nd: " + (competitors.length >= 2 ? competitors[1].getName() : "n/a");
        details += "\n     3rd: " + (competitors.length >= 3 ? competitors[2].getName() : "n/a");
    }
    return details;
}
```

Comment: what should i do to make n/a appear in the case when the competitor has not finished the race? e.g.:
1st: David
2nd: n/a
3rd: n/a

Comment: @user2839383 - Then use the second `toString()` instead of the first one; it basically checks on an individual basis that there actually IS a first-place finisher, a second-place finisher, etc.

Comment: Can I do it without using the second toString() by any chance?

Comment: @user2839383 - I don't understand; you'd be using the second `toString()` in place of the first one (replacing the function altogether).